# Problem installing cudnn8, sbin/ldconfig.real: "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64" is not a known library type

Tags: linux, nvidia, cudnn

I been getting this error while trying to install cudnn 8 with the debian distribution downloaded from here.

`/sbin/ldconfig.real: "/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64" is not a known library type`

All the related config files in `ld.so.conf.d` include the above path, running `ldconfig` receive the same error.

Anyone knows what's happening?

Comment: Something is broken in your ldconfig setup. This has nothing to do with CUDA or CUDNN per se.

Answer (score 0):

apparently commenting out `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64` in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/lib_cuda.conf` was enough to fix the issue. Not sure what impact is gonna bring but at least the error message is gone

Comment: The more pertinent question is who or what added it in the first place. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is shell variable for influence link-loader behaviour. It should never be set in ld.so.conf